# Can you combine multiple rental incomes and expenses for tax purposes in Canada?

Tags: income-tax, canada, rental-property, canada-revenue-agency

I have been reporting my rental properties income and expenses separately using tax filling program called [GenuTax](https://www.genutax.ca).

It's rather time involved, to simplify things I am wondering if it is possible to combine them and how would I do that?

We are not incorporated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the answer and it is a **yes** - however if someone can confirm that would be great:

> How much can I claim for depreciation? In general, depreciation on a
>   rental property cannot be used to either create or increase your
>   rental loss. When more than one rental property is owned, all net
>   rental income (or loss) is **combined** to determine the total income or
>   loss for the year.

Source: http://www.taxplanningguide.ca/tax-planning-guide/section-3-investors/rental-properties/